# Comparar Elementos Duplicados En Dos Listas en Python "Mostrar Por Consola Si Existen o No"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito resolver un ejercicio y he quedado un poco estancado en la lógica de programación.
¡ Soy nuevo en este campo !

**Este es el ejercicio y dice lo siguiente:**

Desarrolla un programa en Python que nos permita conocer el primer elemento duplicado en una lista.

El usuario podrá crear una lista de longitud n.
El usuario podrá definir la longitud y cada uno de los elementos dentro de la lista.
Todo los elementos dentro de la lista serán números enteros.
El programa deberá **mostrar en consola el primer elemento duplicado de la lista**.
**En caso no existan elementos duplicados**, el *programa deberá retornar el siguiente mensaje*:
**No existen elementos duplicados.**

Este es el proceso del código que estaba realizando, el problema es que no logro que se ejecute solamente **No existen elementos duplicados.** se imprime los dos (numero duplicado y no existe el elemento):

```
longitudLista = int(input('Longitud de la lista: '))
lista = []
contador = 0
repetidos = []
newLista = []



while contador < longitudLista:
  agregarNum = int(input('Ingrese un elemento: '))
  lista.append(agregarNum)
  contador = contador + 1

for i in lista:
  if i not in newLista:
    newLista.append(i)
  else:
    repetidos.append(i)

print('No existen elementos duplicados.')

for k in repetidos:
  for l in newLista:
    if k == l:
      print(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La cosa es que puedes ir ingresando la lista y buscando el primer duplicado en la misma pasada.

Para esto definimos la variable `duplicado`, que contendrá el primer valor duplicado. Inicialmente está en `None`, pues no existe elemento duplicado:

```
lista = []
duplicado = None
n = int(input("Ingrese # de elementos: "))
for i in range(n):
    valor = input("Ingrese valor: ")
    if valor in lista and not duplicado:
        duplicado = valor
    lista.append(valor)

if duplicado:
    print(f"Primer elemento duplicado: {duplicado}")
else:
    print("No existen elementos duplicados")
```

produce:

```
Ingrese # de elementos: 5
Ingrese valor: 1
Ingrese valor: 2
Ingrese valor: 3
Ingrese valor: 1
Ingrese valor: 5
Primer elemento duplicado: 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```

y

```
Ingrese # de elementos: 5
Ingrese valor: 1
Ingrese valor: 2
Ingrese valor: 3
Ingrese valor: 4
Ingrese valor: 5
No existen elementos duplicados

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Gracias mi hermano por tu explicación, aprendí algo nuevo, hasta ahora veo la palabra reservada "not"

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo el código, de como se me ocurre solucionarlo a mí

```
longitudLista = int(input('Longitud de la lista: '))
lista = []
contador = 0
i=0
j=0
duplicado=False
numDuplicado=-1



while contador < longitudLista:
  agregarNum = int(input('Ingrese un elemento: '))
  lista.append(agregarNum)
  contador = contador + 1

while(i<longitudLista and not duplicado):
    j=0
    while(j<longitudLista and not duplicado ):
        if(lista[i]==lista[j] and i!=j):
            duplicado=True
        else:
            j=j+1
    i=i+1

if(duplicado):
    print("El primer elemento duplicado es",lista[i-1])
else:
    print("No existen elementos duplicados")
```

Comment: Gracias, he observado cada respuesta y me ha funcionado bien, por lo visto debo reforzar mi lógica de programación.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la sentencia

```py
print('No existen elementos duplicados.')
```

Se encuentra secuencial a todo el código, si quieres que solo se imprima cuando no encuentre ningún resultado puedes intentar:

```py
if not repetidos: #una lista vacia devuelve falso en python cuando se lo trata de booleano
    print('No existen elementos duplicados.')
else:
    print(repetidos[0]) #primer elemento repetido
```

O de manera más intuitiva

```py
if len(repetidos) == 0: #la lista con repetidos no tiene elementos
    print('No existen elementos duplicados.')
else:
    print(repetidos[0]) #primer elemento repetido
```

Por lo tanto, se puede optimizar de la siguiente manera:

```py
longitudLista = int(input('Longitud de la lista: '))
lista = []
contador = 0
repetido = '' #no necesitas una lista si solo necesitas un resultado 
newLista = []



while contador < longitudLista:
  agregarNum = int(input('Ingrese un elemento: '))
  lista.append(agregarNum)
  contador = contador + 1

for i in lista:
  if i not in newLista:
    newLista.append(i)
  else:
    repetido = i
    break # Una vez encontraste el primer repetido no hace falta seguir en el bucle. 

if repetido == '': #no encontro ningun numero
    print('No existen elementos duplicados.')
else:
    print(repetido) #primer elemento repetido
```

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo y gracias por ayudarme, estuve observando el código y la lógica que implementaste. Me ayudo mucho .